# Run karma on file change from command line/npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-mocha, npm-scripts

I have unit testing for an app set up with karma & mocha & reporting through istanbul.

npm script:

```
"test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start tests/karma.conf.js --single-run",
```

What I want to do is have a script to run during development that will watch test & app files for changes and re-run the tests as needed.

I tried replacing `--single-run` with `--auto-watch`:

```
"test:watch": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start tests/karma.conf.js --auto-watch",
```

but this re-runs continuously - as soon as one round of tests are finished, it starts over.

karma.conf.js:

```
var webpackConfig = require('../build/webpack.conf.test');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon-chai', 'phantomjs-shim'],
    reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'],
    files: ['./index.js'],
    preprocessors: {
      './index.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: './coverage',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'lcov', subdir: '.' },
        { type: 'text' }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

webpack.conf.test.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf.js');
var eslintFormatter = require('eslint-friendly-formatter');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);
}

module.exports = {
  devtool: '#inline-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/js'),
    filename: 'build.js',
    publicPath: '/ntx/js/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
      'scss-loader': 'sass-loader'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: '"testing"' }
    })
  ],
  // use inline sourcemap for karma-sourcemap-loader
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, sourceMap: false } }] },
      { test: /\.postcss$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, sourceMap: false } }] },
      { test: /\.less$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, sourceMap: false } }, { loader: 'less-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }] },
      { test: /\.sass$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, sourceMap: false } }, { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: false, indentedSyntax: true } }] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, sourceMap: false } }, { loader: 'scss-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }] },
      { test: /\.stylus$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, sourceMap: false } }, { loader: 'stylus-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }] },
      { test: /\.styl$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, sourceMap: false } }, { loader: 'stylus-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }] },
      { test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: eslintFormatter
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            css: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, souremap: false } }],
            postcss: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, souremap: false } }],
            less: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, souremap: false } }, { loader: 'less-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }],
            sass: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, souremap: false } }, { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: false, indentedSyntax: true } }],
            scss: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, souremap: false } }, { loader: 'scss-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }],
            stylus: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, souremap: false } }, { loader: 'stylus-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }],
            styl: ['vue-style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: false, souremap: false } }, { loader: 'stylus-loader', options: { sourceMap: false } }],
          },
          transformToRequire: {
            video: 'src',
            source: 'src',
            img: 'src',
            image: 'xlink:href'
          }
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      }, {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: path.posix.join('./dist/img', 'img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Karma configuration options](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html).

You can use `--no-single-run` instead of `--single-run` to run the tests in **watch mode**.  You should be able to run this with `--auto-watch` too.

Comment: This has the same problem that simply leaving out `--single-run` has: it does not wait for changes to any files, it repeats the test suite as soon as it has completed one run. I want it to re-run only when files change.

Comment: Are you using a karma configuration file?

Comment: Yes - I can't believe I didn't put that in first time around! Added.